# Android GridView with ImageView problem

Tags: java, android, gridview, textview

So I programaticaly build grids in this loop

```
 for(int i = 0; i<f; i++){  //f is number of gridview to create
          RelativeLayout r = new RelativeLayout(this);
          r.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
          realViewSwitcher.addView(r);
      GridView j1 = new GridView(this);
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_center =
          new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      params_center.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
      j1.setNumColumns(3); 
      j1.setLayoutParams(params_center);
      j1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);    
      r.addView(j1);      
      }
```

Then I Have a String array that contains some names. How to I set up these names into gridviews. example: i have 27 names, 3 gridview with 3 columns. First 9 names are on first grid,  9-18 names are on the second gridivew and 18-27 are on the third.

WOuld be even better to display an image bas on another strign array containing 'true'  or 'false'. Example. we display 0-9 people, then check array[0-9] and if it is true we set a pic to for example name 1 , if false we set name 1 another pic.

Answer (score 0):

why are you creating multiple gridViews for this? just use an adapter and have your logic in it. Ask google for good tutorials on this. You will have issues with having multiple scroll components in a single activity. there is a workaround to this which involves a scroll view and a custom grid view object, but before you even go there i dont believe you should be using multiple gridViews for your case. and in any case the whole logic for what you want to do can be added to a custom gridView adapter, as for the check you can also do that inside the adapter.